# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen „öffnen/aufmachen“ und „aufschlagen“?

Tags: meaning

Beispielsätze:

- Öffne die Augen (/das Buch/die Tür/das Fenster)!
- Mach die Augen (/das Buch/die Tür/das Fenster) auf!
- Schlag die Augen (/das Buch/die Tür/das Fenster) auf!

Klingen sie natürlich??

Comment: Eine Tür/Ein Fenster kann man zuschlagen, aber nicht aufschlagen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bücher, Augenlider, Sahne, Zelte, Lager und Frühstückseier kann man *aufschlagen* - alles andere nicht (wobei sich nur die ersten zwei Verwendungen mit *öffnen* und *aufmachen* überlappen).

Bücher, Türen, Augen, und Verpackungen kann man *aufmachen*, genauso wie *öffnen*. Ein Zelt kann man *aufmachen und öffnen*, das ist aber was Anderes, als wenn man es *aufschlägt*.

*öffnen* und *aufmachen* sind damit enge Synonyme, *aufschlagen* hat nur eine leichte Überlappung in einigen Bedeutungen.

[Wie man vielleicht heraushört, ist das eine Anregung zur Benutzung eines Wörterbuchs]

Comment: *öffnen* und *aufmachen* können in vielen Fällen synonym benutzt werden, aber auch nicht immer - ein Mensch, der sich öffnet und ein Mensch, der sich aufmacht, tun sehr verschiedene Dinge.

Answer (score 2):

Ich selbst kenne "*aufschlagen*" (mit dieser Bedeutung) nur im Zusammenhang mit Büchern (bzw. Prospekten oder sonstigen Schriften).

Bei der Tür und dem Fenster kenne ich "*öffnen*" nur in "offiziellen" Texten, während ich "*aufmachen*" eher in Umgangssprache kenne.

Im Falle von den Augen ist es ähnlich; allerdings hat "*die Augen aufmachen*" noch eine zweite Bedeutung: Nämlich "nicht alles glauben" ...

Wenn jemand sagt:

> Mach die Augen auf.

... wird dies in sehr vielen Fällen bedeuten: "Schau genau hin. Glaube nicht alles, was man dir sagt."